# Exclude virtual fields

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a virtual field `fullname`:

```
UserSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function() {  
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
});
```

Sometimes I want this field in my query result and sometimes I don't. I haven't figured out how to exclude it. This is what I have tried (didn't change anything):

```
UserModel.findOne({ '_id': userId })
  .select('-fullname')
  .exec(callback);
```

Should I approach this in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to disable virtuals in `toJSON` and in `toObject` and include them in the query you want them

```
UserModel.findOne({ _id: userId })
   .then(doc => console.log(doc.toObject({ virtuals: true }));
```

If you want to exclude specific fields you can just delete them before sending the doc.

```
UserModel.findOne({ _id: userId })
   .then(doc => doc.toObject({ virtuals: true }))
   .then(doc => {
     delete doc.mySecretVirtual;
     return doc;
   });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Is it maybe because I have set `toObject` and `toJSON` as `{virtuals: true}` in my model?

Comment: Yes, if you set them in `toObject` and `toJSON` they cannot be ommited as far as i know, I've updated my answer maybe it will solve the problem

Comment: Okay, this seems to work basically. But this way if I want to exclude a virtual field I have to exclude all virtual fields. Is there a way to exclude one and include another?

Comment: I geuss you could just delete them after you query the doc, updated my answer

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. I'll wait a little bit before I accept to see if there are maybe other opinions.